# IIS 7.5- Allow internal users access but internet users require password

Tags: iis-7.5

I have an IIS 7.5 website that I want to allow anyone coming in from the internet to require a password before they can view the site (Basic Authentication), whereas anyone coming from internal network should not need a password.

How would I go about this?

Comment: typically the way I see this handled is just to get integrated authentication working such that people on the local domain authenticate automatically and people externally have to enter their credentials. make sure to use https if you're using basic auth.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment! This server isn't on a domain- will that make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different methods for this.  Since this system is not on a domain, you can't take advantage of integrated security like AD.

That said, if the websites are hosting primarily static data, you can create 2 copies of the site, with 2 different IP's, and then simply setup authentication for the public site, and leave the private wide open.

So in effect, you have a PUBLIC site, and a PRIVATE site, but both point to the same root directory.  That's the quick and easy way since you have easy authentication mechanism like Active Directory to filter requests.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I was thinking about doing this. i think this would be the easiest!

Comment: I ended up going down this path, so thankyou

Comment: Glad that I could help!  If you need any additional help, please don't hesitate to reach out!  I'm happy to lend assistance my friend!